# Can't click submit buttons due to Float:left

Tags: html, css, layout

The title says it all, I have 2 buttons who need to float left,
but when I assign `float:left;` to the corresponding css, the buttons get "unclickable" they do appear, but I can't interact with them. When I remove the `float:left;` they do work, but then they're not on the place where I want them to be.

Also my FireBug doesn't give any error messages, and this problem only occurs in Google Chrome. If anyone has any suggestions please share them with me.

Here's a part of the code :

HTML :

```
<div id="php_beam" class="php_beam">
    <form method="post" action="index.php">            
        <!-- PHP Beam Buttons -->
        <input type="submit" name="Previous"    value="Vorige" />
        <input type="submit" name="Next"        value="Volgende" />
     </form>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.php_beam
{
    width:              950px;
    height:             20px;
    margin-left:        225px;
    margin-top:         5px;
    float:              left;
}
```

To be clear, I want to know if there's an other solution instead of using `float:left;` because that seems to cause the problem.

Comment: @NullPonyPointer nope that doesn't help at all. the float doesnt seem to work at all when defined in the `<form>`

Comment: what is `<!-- PHP Beam Buttons -->` ? are you using anything else ?

Comment: Can you try to replicate the issue in jsFiddle? Would be easier for us to debug it :)

Comment: Thats a comment, the code Shown above is the only code inside that `<div>`

Comment: you can use `position:relative` or `position:absolute` then assign `left` and `right` example: `left:5px;` `right:5px;`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.php_beam
{
    width:              950px;
    height:             20px;
    margin-left:        225px;
    margin-top:         5px;
}

.php_beam input
{
    float:              left;
}
```